# Execute postgreSQL stored procedure as one transaction

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, transactions, commit, autocommit

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and I have some stored procedures created which contains several statements. I'm calling this stored procedures in a Java application with the help of a prepared statement.

Now I've read that each statement inside the stored procedure is executed as a transaction, i.e. one commit after each statement. But what I want is to have the whole stored procedure executed as one transaction, i.e. only one commit.

How can I do this? Perhaps deactivating autocommit on the JDBC level?

Comment: Disable autocommit and call the function after starting a transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh you mean first dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false); (transaction block starts) then I do the prepared statement and then I do dbConnection.commit();. Is this right? Do I have to care about rollback?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, basically stored procedures **are** atomic in nature and executed as one transaction.

```
CREATE TABLE xxx (id int PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  len int;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction ID: %', TXID_CURRENT();
  INSERT INTO xxx VALUES (1);

  RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction ID: %', TXID_CURRENT();
  INSERT INTO xxx VALUES (2);

  RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction ID: %', TXID_CURRENT();
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx INTO len;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Number of records: %', len;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction ID: %', TXID_CURRENT();

  -- results in unique constraint violation
  UPDATE xxx SET id = 3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then try invoking `f()` from `psql`.

```
stackoverflow=# show autocommit;
 autocommit 
------------
 on
(1 row)

stackoverflow=# SELECT f();
NOTICE:  Transaction ID: 15086
NOTICE:  Transaction ID: 15086
NOTICE:  Transaction ID: 15086
NOTICE:  Number of records: 2
NOTICE:  Transaction ID: 15086
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "xxx_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE xxx SET id = 3"
PL/pgSQL function f() line 20 at SQL statement

stackoverflow=# SELECT * FROM xxx;
id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Comment: And not only that, but you couldn't `COMMIT` in a stored procedure even if you wanted to.