# Does a procedure run in a transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, relational-database

If a procedure fails in middle, are changes at that point from the beginning of SP rolled back implicitly or do we have to write any explicit code to make sure that SP runs in a transaction only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute postgreSQL stored procedure as one transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406111/execute-postgresql-stored-procedure-as-one-transaction)

Comment: All covered in the manual. Including the fact that you don't technically have stored procedures in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 46):

The term often (incorrectly) refers to a **function** ([`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)), which provides much of the same functionality (and more) as other RDBMS provide with a "stored procedure".

The true stored **procedure** ([`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)) as defined in the ISO/IEC standard was introduced with **Postgres 11**. The main difference (among others) is transaction handling. See:

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)
- [What are the differences between “Stored Procedures” and “Stored Functions”?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2381/3684)

Either of them **always runs in a transaction context**. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html):

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed
> within a transaction. If you do not issue a `BEGIN` command, then each
> individual statement has an implicit `BEGIN` and (if successful)
> `COMMIT` wrapped around it.

#### [Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

... cannot `COMMIT`. It is *atomic* - **succeeds or fails *completely*.**

Well, there is error handling in PL/pgSQL. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

> By default, any error occurring in a PL/pgSQL function aborts
> execution of the function and the surrounding transaction. You can
> trap errors and recover from them by using a `BEGIN` block with an
> `EXCEPTION` clause.

Do not confuse [PL/pgSQL `BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) (start of a code block) with [SQL `BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html) (start of a transaction).

#### [Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)

... allows `COMMIT` - which immediately starts a new transaction. There is fine print to this in [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

> A new transaction starts out with default transaction characteristics
> such as transaction isolation level. In cases where transactions are
> committed in a loop, it might be desirable to start new transactions
> automatically with the same characteristics as the previous one. The
> commands `COMMIT AND CHAIN` and `ROLLBACK AND CHAIN` accomplish this.

#### [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) (executing anonymous code blocks)

Starting with **Postgres 11** (when [procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) were introduced), transaction control statements are also allowed in anonymous code blocks executed with the [**`DO`** command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). See:

- [Do PL/pgSQL functions autocommit on their own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219168/do-pl-pgsql-functions-autocommit-on-their-own/67241570#67241570)
- [COMMIT works in one plpgsql code block, but not in another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290944/3684)

#### Exceptions

Commands like `VACUUM`, `CREATE DATABASE`, or `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` do not run in a transaction context and are not allowed at all in a PL/pgSQL code block.

Some things can never be rolled back, including:

- data written to log files
- changes made to a sequence. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)

  > **Important**: Some PostgreSQL data types and functions have special rules
  > regarding transactional behavior. In particular, changes made to a
  > sequence (and therefore the counter of a column declared using `serial`)
  > are immediately visible to all other transactions and are not rolled
  > back if the transaction that made the changes aborts.
- prepared statements (old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7bc0e/25) demo)
- dblink calls (or similar). See:

  - [Does Postgres support nested or autonomous transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425944/postgres-supports-nested-transaction-or-autonomus-transactions-or-not/25428060#25428060)

Comment: I saw the links in your answers but the doc doesn't clearly say that `transaction is used in functions and procedures implicitly`. So, I don't know where I can make sure your answer is true.

Comment: @SuperKai-KazuyaIto: It's not that a *"transaction is used in functions and procedures implicitly"*. Rather, a function can only be executed within a transaction to begin with. There is a quote (with link to the manual) in my answer saying just that: *"Functions and trigger procedures are always executed within a transaction established by an outer query ..."* More basics here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: The link `postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html` no longer has `"Functions and trigger procedures are always executed within a transaction established by an outer query ..."` because it was updated.

Comment: @SuperKai: Well, it was the [other link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html). But all the same, the manual has been reworked with the addition of procedures. I updated my answer now to reflect that. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Postgres 14 procedure like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_error(schema_name text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
declare
<declare any vars that you need>
BEGIN
<do your thing>
END
$$;
```

For all practical purposes, code written in between the `BEGIN` and `END` block is executed in a single transaction. Hence, if any of the statements in the block fail, all the previous statements will be rolled back automatically. You do not need to explicitly write any roll back code.

However, there are special cases where one can have fine grained control over when to start/commit/rollback transactions. Refer to : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

From the official document of Postgresql:

> In procedures invoked by the CALL command as well as in anonymous code
> blocks (DO command), it is possible to end transactions using the
> commands COMMIT and ROLLBACK. A new transaction is started
> automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so
> there is no separate START TRANSACTION command. (Note that BEGIN and
> END have different meanings in PL/pgSQL.)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

A procedure is run in a transaction so if there is error, the transaction is rollbacked.

For example, you create `my_proc()` procedure which sets `5` to `my.var` then can cause `division by zero` error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(INOUT value INTEGER) AS $$
BEGIN
SET my.var = 5; -- Here
SELECT 1/value INTO value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_proc(1)` then `5` is set to `my.var` successfully as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# CALL my_proc(1);
 my_func
---------
       1
(1 row)
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 5
(1 row)
```

Now, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_proc(0)` then `division by zero`  error occurs, then `my.var` is still `2` as shown below because `my_proc()` procedure is rollbacked:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# CALL my_proc(0);
ERROR:  division by zero
...
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 2
(1 row)
```