# How do I chain a VACUUM off of a purge routine running with pg_cron?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, vacuum, pg-cron

Postgres 13.4

I've got some `pg_cron` jobs set up to periodically delete older records out of log-like files. What I'd like to do is to run `VACUUM ANALYZE` after performing a purge. Unfortunately, I can't work out how to do this in a stored function. Am I missing a trick? Is a stored procedure more appropriate?

As an example, here's one of my purge routines

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dba.purge_event_log (
    retain_days_in integer_positive default 14)

RETURNS int4

AS $BODY$

WITH  -- Use a CTE so that we've got a way of returning the count easily.
deleted AS (

-- Normal-looking code for this requires a literal:
-- where your_dts < now() - INTERVAL '14 days'
-- Don't want to use a literal, SQL injection, etc.
-- Instead, using a interval constructor to achieve the same result:

   DELETE
     FROM dba.event_log
    WHERE dts < now() - make_interval (days => $1)
RETURNING *
),

----------------------------------------
-- Save details to a custom log table
----------------------------------------
logit AS (
insert into dba.event_log (name, details)
    values ('purge_event_log(' || retain_days_in::text || ')',
             'count = ' || (select count(*)::text from deleted)
           )
)

----------------------------------------
-- Return result count
----------------------------------------
select count(*) from deleted;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION dba.purge_event_log (integer_positive) IS
'Delete dba.event_log records older than the day count passed in, with a default retention period of 14 days.';
```

The truth is, I don't really care about the `count(*)` result from this routine, *in this case*. But I might want a result *and* an additional action in some other, similar context. As you can see, the routine deletes records, uses a CTE to `insert` a report into another table, and then returns a result. No matter what, I figure this example is a good way to get me head around the alternatives and options in stored functions. The main thing I want to achieve here is to delete records, and then run maintenance. if this is an awkward fit for a stored function or procedure, I could write out an entry to a `vacuum_list` table with the table name, and have another job to run though that list.

If there's a smarter way to approach `vacuum` without the extra, I'm of course interested in that. But I'm also interested in understanding the limits on what operationa you can combine in PL/PgSQL routines.

Pavel Stehule' answer is correct and complete. I decided to follow-up a bit here as I like to dig in on bugs in my code, behaviors in Postgres, etc. to get a better sense of what I'm dealing with. I'm including some notes below for anyone who finds them of use.

## COMMAND cannot be executed...

The reference to "VACUUM cannot be executed inside a transaction block" gave me a better way to search the docs for similarly restricted commands. The information below probably doesn't cover everything, but it's a start.

```
Command                Limitation
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE         If creating a new table space.
DROP DATABASE
CLUSTER                Without any parameters.
CREATE TABLESPACE
DROP TABLESPACE
REINDEX                All in system catalogs, database, or schema.

CREATE SUBSCRIPTION    When creating a replication slot (the default behavior.)
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION     With refresh option as true.
DROP SUBSCRIPTION      If the subscription is associated with a replication slot.

COMMIT PREPARED
ROLLBACK PREPARED
DISCARD ALL

VACUUM
```

The accepted answer indicates that the limitation has nothing to do with the specific server-side language used. I've just come across an older thread that has some excellent explanations and links for stored functions and transactions:

[Do stored procedures run in database transaction in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/do-stored-procedures-run-in-database-transaction-in-postgres)

## Sample Code

I also wondered about stored procedures, as they're allowed to control transactions. I tried them out in PG 13 and, no, the code is treated like a stored function, down to the error messages.

For anyone that goes in for this sort of thing, here are the "hello world" samples of sQL and PL/PgSQL stored functions and procedures to test out how `VACCUM` behaves in these cases. Spoiler: It doesn't work, as advertised.

### SQL Function

```
/*
select * from dba.vacuum_sql_function();

Fails:
ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function
CONTEXT:  SQL function "vacuum_sql_function" statement 1. 0.000 seconds. (Line 13).
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dba.vacuum_sql_function();

CREATE FUNCTION dba.vacuum_sql_function()
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE sql

AS $sql_code$

VACUUM ANALYZE activity;

$sql_code$;

select * from dba.vacuum_sql_function(); -- Fails.
```

### PL/PgSQL Function

```
/*
select * from dba.vacuum_plpgsql_function();

Fails:
ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "VACUUM ANALYZE activity"
PL/pgSQL function vacuum_plpgsql_function() line 4 at SQL statement. 0.000 seconds. (Line 22).
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dba.vacuum_plpgsql_function();

CREATE FUNCTION dba.vacuum_plpgsql_function()
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $plpgsql_code$

BEGIN
VACUUM ANALYZE activity;
END

$plpgsql_code$;

select * from dba.vacuum_plpgsql_function();
```

### SQL Procedure

```
/*
call dba.vacuum_sql_procedure();

ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function
CONTEXT:  SQL function "vacuum_sql_procedure" statement 1. 0.000 seconds. (Line 20).
*/

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dba.vacuum_sql_procedure();

CREATE PROCEDURE dba.vacuum_sql_procedure()
LANGUAGE SQL

AS $sql_code$

VACUUM ANALYZE activity;

$sql_code$;

call dba.vacuum_sql_procedure();
```

### PL/PgSQL Procedure

```
 /*
call dba.vacuum_plpgsql_procedure();

ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "VACUUM ANALYZE activity"
PL/pgSQL function vacuum_plpgsql_procedure() line 4 at SQL statement. 0.000 seconds. (Line 23).
*/

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dba.vacuum_plpgsql_procedure();

CREATE PROCEDURE dba.vacuum_plpgsql_procedure()
LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $plpgsql_code$

BEGIN
VACUUM ANALYZE activity;
END

$plpgsql_code$;

call dba.vacuum_plpgsql_procedure();
```

## Other Options

Plenty. As I understand it, `VACUUM`, and a handful of other commands, are not supported in server-side code running within Postgres. Therefore, you code needs to start from somewhere else. That can be:

- Whatever `cron` you've got in your server's OS.
- Any exteral client you like.
- `pg_cron`.

As we're deployed on RDS, those last two options are where I'll look. And there's one more:

- Let `AUTOVACCUM` and an occasional `VACCUM` do their thing.

That's pretty easy to do, and seems to work fine for the bulk of our needs.

## Another Idea

If you do want a bit more control and some custom logging, I'm imagining a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dba.vacuum_list (
    database_name   text,
    schema_name     text,
    table_name      text,
    run             boolean,
    run_analyze     boolean,
    run_full        boolean,
    last_run_dts    timestamp)

ALTER TABLE dba.vacuum_list ADD CONSTRAINT
   vacuum_list_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (database_name, schema_name, table_name);
```

That's just a sketch. The idea is like this:

- You `INSERT` into `vacuum_list` when a table needs some vacuuming, at least as far as you're concerned.
- In my case, that would be an `UPSERT` as I don't need a full log-like table, just a single row per table of interest with the last outcome and/or pending state.
- Periodically, a remote client, etc. connects, reads the table, and executes each specified `VACUUM`, according to the options specified in the record.
- The external client updates the row with the last run timestamp, and whatever else you're including in the row.
- Optionally, you could include fields for duration and change in relation size pre:post vacuuming.

That last option is what I'm interested in. None of our `VACUUM` calls were working for quite some time as there was a months-old dead connection from something sever-side. `VACUUM` appears to run fine, in such a case, it just can't delete a whole lot of rows. (Because of the super old "open" transaction ID, visibility maps, etc.) The only way to see this sort of thing seems to be to `VACUUM VERBOSE` and study the output. Or to record vacuum time and, more important, relation size change to flag cases where nothing seems to happen, when it seems like it should.

Comment: Add vacuum in pg_cron just after this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VACUUM` is "top level" command. It cannot be executed from PL/pgSQL ever or from any other PL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does anyone know if the documentation includes a discussion of this that I can check? I'd like to get a better sense of what I can and cannot do from a stored function.

Comment: @MorrisdeOryx - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html *VACUUM cannot be executed inside a transaction block.*, and any PL/pgSQL code should to be executed under transaction. I think so top only commands are CREATE DROP DATABASE and VACUUM.